# Is it possible to increase attribute values of a created female wrestler in SmackDown 5

Tags: ps2, wwe-smackdown-hctp

Playing the classic Smackdown: Here comes the pain,I am unable to level up the attributes of a created female superstar via the season mode. For that matter,I am not even able to select the created superstar in the season mode.

Can anyone please suggest how to increase the attribute values of a created female superstar? Is it even possible? As the game is pretty old, Google is not of much help. Hope someone in this community remembers the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smackdown! Here Comes the Pain does not allow female created superstars to wrestle in Season mode. In order to wrestle as a female in Season mode you'll need to edit the superstar and change the Gender from Female to Male.

You'll never be able to compete for the Women's Championship either. You can not request a Women's title match from the General Manager of RAW or Smackdown!

Great classic game, definitely my favorite of the series.